# Illegal argument exception while creating an app through kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am experiencing this error , can someone guide me .Line 43 is this
`mCanvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w,h,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888`)

[image]

Comment: Your view probably has a size of 0 for width or height. This could be due to layout params for the ViewGroup it's in, or how you handled `onMeasure()`. That's one issue you'll need to fix, but you should probably also skip creating the bitmap and canvas when the width or height is zero, so the class is safer to use in layouts that may change size.

Comment: Turns out it was an issue in my XML file. Have resolved it now , thanks